# How to show a date in french format with IReport

Tags: java, date, format, ireport

I'm trying to show a date  in jasper report with french format  . I change the options of this report but everytime I get a date in english . What can I do please ?

Here is some picture of what I get :

[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/975899rapport.jpg]

I use also parameters but it doesn't work

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("date", new java.util.Date());
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.FRENCH);
```

Comment: Well what is the date format you want. Some example will help. May be this will help you [----> 2.41.23.Four different date formats for four countries: US, UK, GERMANY, FRANCE](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/FourdifferentdateformatsforfourcountriesUSUKGERMANYFRANCE.htm)

Comment: Thanks but really it's not what I want I don't know why it doesn't working

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: mysql but that date it's not relative to database it's the date of today (java.util.Date())

Comment: If the date is just numbers (2013-03-08), what makes it French?  Did you want the month names spelled out?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thats why I gave him link and asked for exmple, but he said thats not what he wants. His requirement is quite unclear.

Comment: @Smit: Yep.  I'm guessing the SimpleDateFormat for a French date would be "d MMM yyyy" or "d MMMM yyyy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It this what you seek?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateFormats {

    public static String frenchDate() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.FRANCE)
            .format(new Date());
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(frenchDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Mekes sense! Helpful when changing the query is not a solution.

Comment: @Katedral Pillon this is what I get when I use your methode: [1]:http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/171651date2.jpg

Comment: @Majda If you could give some example what is your requirement then it will be easy to help you out.

Comment: When I do that :                                System.out.println("Test Date: " + new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy", Locale.FRANCE)
            .format(new Date()));  it shows me on my console  the date in french like that : "mardi 19 mars 2013" so my problem is on my report it shows me the date in english even if I change to French Locale

Comment: I have edited the format for you to play around with: `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy`. Change it to what you want. Right now it should give you something like `mar. mars 19 09:37:59 2013`. `mar` for mardi.

Comment: Also, if you are sending a string to your display/report as in my example, it should be able to just print the string and not reformat it somehow.

Comment: @Majda remember to mark your thread as answered so others know. You do that by clicking the check mark near this response and it should turn green.

Comment: @Katedral Pillon yea sure I didn't know that i'm new here

Answer (score -1):

Add an string field and edit expression as follows:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd '-' MM '-' yyyy").format(new Date())
```

Tweak above as needed, such as changing `new Date()` for your Date field, check out documentation for SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not really the problem. I want to have a date in french even if I change location that doesn't work